# How create middleware on laravel SPA from cretueusebiu

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

iam new and just learning about laravel SPA . i try to create project laravel spa from github : https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa .

so next step i want to add middleware , but in the structure i dont know what happens to do .

this folder on

```
js
  middleware
        admin.js
        auth.js
        check-auth.js
        guest.js
        locale.js
```

on admin.js

```
import store from '~/store'

export default (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters['auth/user'].role !== 'admin') {
    next({ name: 'home' })
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

this role is admin but on table users i didnt see anything about role or anything , please tell me . 
someone who already uses this , i just wanna ask , how to can create some middleware like , users ,admin ,super admin , or anything . thankyou

Comment: Can you share the code you already tried?

Comment: this all code is work normally , but i dont know what the step to create to another middleware

Comment: That specific middleware `admin.js` isn't enabled by default.   Do you want to use that middleware or just create something similar to it?

Comment: yes i want to enable this middleware but i dont know how to do

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking to make are called guards (or gates) generally. This is usually accomplished by middleware alright but middleware can be used for a lot more.

In your specific instance you can enable the `admin.js` middleware in a component by adding `middleware: 'admin'` to the component script.

You're right about the role field on user. You'll need to add roles to the user table (and maybe the model too). You'll should be able to see it in the Vue dev tools. 
You can add it as a text field or an enum really for now. There are better ways using a roles table. But an enum is quick and dirty.

`admin.js` only guards against a role of "admin" so you can just copy / paste the file and change `store.getters['auth/user'].role !== 'admin'` to whatever role you want to guard. 
Any files in the `js/middleware/` dir look to be autoloaded from `js/router/index.js`

For example if you make a middleware called `superUser.js` and change the guard to `store.getters['auth/user'].role !== 'superUser'`
You would add `middleware: 'superUser'` to your component.

Comment: so i just need add a table role and  middleware: 'admin'  in the router.js  ?

Comment: You might be able to add it in router.js. 
But the loading looks like it takes it from a key `middleware:` on the component itself.
If you just want it to work you'll need to add a _role_ field to the user table, go for the roles table if you want but you'll need to do work to have it available in the vuex store under the user object